# Popular comboBox através de uma consulta no banco

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, combobox

Galera sei que estou fazendo da maneira errada para popular o meu comboBox, estou fazendo isso do lado do cliente ao invés de fazer do lado do servidor é que java não é minha praia .

Estou tentando popular o meu comboBox da seguinte maneira:
Mas da erro **cannot find symbol class conectar** logo abaixo do try na linha Connection conexao = new BancoDeDados.conectar();

```
 <select name = "usuario">
                                     <%
                                        try {
                                        Connection conexao = new BancoDeDados.conectar();
                                        Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
                                        ResultSet rs; 
                                        //rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM supplier "); 
                                        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NOME as nome,EMAIL as email FROM `usuario`");
                                        while(rs.next()) {
                                            out.write("<option value=" + rs.getString("email") + ">" + rs.getString("name") + "</option>");

                                        }
                                        rs.close();
                                        stmt.close();
                                        } 

                                        catch(Exception e) {
                                            System.err.print("Erro!");
                                                           }
                                        %>
                                    </select>
```

Classe banco de dados:

```
    private final String nomeDoBanco;
    private final String login;
    private final String senha;
    private final String host;

    private BancoDeDados() {
        /*
     Trecho de código usado para "Registrar" o driver da JDBC na JVM. 
     Idealmente, é executado apenas uma vez, como é o caso aqui.
         */
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        /*
     Definições das informações de conexão do banco de dados.
         */
        this.nomeDoBanco = "trabalhodw2";
        this.login = "usuariodw2";
        this.senha = "senhadw2";
        this.host = "localhost";
    }

    public static BancoDeDados getInstance() {
        return instancia;
    }

    /*
     Método usado para retornar uma conexão válida ao nosso banco de dados.
     */
    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + nomeDoBanco, login, senha);
        return conexao;
    }
```

Comment: Seu construtor é privado e você está dando `new`. Isso é apenas um dos erros, sua conexão está recebendo valores que não existem, já que as atribuições do construtor  `private BancoDeDados()` nunca é invocado. Adicione a classe inteira, pois parece que há mais erros.

Comment: Usa JSTL amigão ;-)